# REPE CMPSB problems

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, disassembly, tasm

i'm trying to use rep cmpsb as following:

```
    DSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA' 

    SOURCE DB 'ASDF'
    TARGET DB 'ASDF'

    SIZE EQU ($-TARGET)



DSEG ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'

SSEG ENDS    

CSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'

    ASSUME CS:CSEG,DS:DSEG,SS:SSEG,ES:NOTHING 


MAIN:

    MOV AX,DSEG
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV SI,OFFSET SOURCE
    MOV DI,OFFSET TARGET

    CLD

    MOV CX,SIZE

    REPE CMPSB



    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

CSEG ENDS
END MAIN
```

i'm using emu8086.
tried rep and repe but nothing happens.
rep should actually repeat until cx>0 either two strings are equal or not but it doesn't happen and it runs only one time (after program terminated,cx is 3)
i also tried repe for two equal strings but nothing happened neither
when running in these two modes,zero flag never changes,that i think it should be changed to repe work correctly
so only repne works until cx=0 and doesn't give the correct result
so what should i try?

---------solved---------------
works after initialize ES:

```
 DSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA' 

    SOURCE DB 'ASDF'
    TARGET DB 'ASDF'

    SIZE EQU ($-TARGET)



DSEG ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'

SSEG ENDS

ESEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'EXTRA'

ESEG ENDS    

CSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'

    ASSUME CS:CSEG,DS:DSEG,SS:SSEG,ES:ESEG 


MAIN:

    MOV AX,DSEG
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV ES, AX

    MOV SI,OFFSET SOURCE
    MOV DI,OFFSET TARGET

    CLD

    MOV CX,SIZE

    REPE CMPSB



    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

CSEG ENDS
END MAIN
```

Comment: Try initializing `ES` register because `CMPS` compares `DS:SI` to `ES:DI`. Add `MOV ES, AX` after `MOV DS, AX`.

Comment: The use of `REP` or `REPE` is assembler dependent. You will need to check the exact documentation for qemu (or the assembler you are using). There is more information here (maybe a duplicate) [**Confused with CMPSB instruction**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552579/confused-with-cmpsb-instruction).